# Correct use of autofs "hosts" map option?

Tags: autofs

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I have an NFS server set up to export some directories. The client machine (also Ubuntu 14.04) is using autofs with the following in /etc/auto.master:

```
/net    -hosts suid
```

But if I ls /net it shows it's empty.

However, if I do:

```
showmount -e  10.10.10.103
```

it lists the exports.

I notice that -d shows nothing though:

```
showmount -d 10.10.10.103
Directories on 10.10.10.103:
```

[The Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) mentions troubleshooting using a foreground automount, so I've tried that and get this (even after I've tried cd to /net in another terminal):

```
gilgongo@alice:~$ sudo automount -f -v
Starting automounter version 5.0.7, master map /etc/auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.02
mounted indirect on /net with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
```

I've also tried using the supplied auto.net script by changing the line in auto.master to:

```
/net   /etc/auto.net
```

But that yields the same result.

I've rather not have entries in /etc/fstab and things, and like the idea of the client picking up the exports in /net. But why isn't the -hosts option working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S0LVED:

I was expecting autofs to show the NFS server name/IP under the /net mount directory and then show the server's exports under that.

So when I did:

```
ls /net/
```

and saw nothing, I concluded it wasn't working.

In fact, what I needed to do was:

```
ls /net/10.10.10.103/
```

and then the exports magically tuned up because I was "accessing" them, which is what autofs is designed to do ("Auto-mounts are mounted only as they are accessed, and are unmounted after a period of inactivity.")

So. There we go. Wuah ho.

Comment: Indeed, it works but it would be better if we could use the DNS name..

Comment: It is possible using DNS name. No reason why it would not work as long as your DNS is working on the client.